# Defining a Coxeter group using all reflections

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, coxeter-groups

Let $(W, S)$ be a pair of a group $W$ and a subset $S$ consisting of involutions of $W$. We can consider the group $\tilde W$ with presentation $\langle S | \mathcal{R} \rangle$ where $\mathcal{R}$ consists of the relations $(st)^{\operatorname{ord}(st)}$ for $s, t \in S$ (the order computed in $W$, of course). If the group homomorphism that sends each $s \in \tilde W$ to the corresponding $s \in W$ is an isomorphism, $(W, S)$ is called a Coxeter system.

The elements $s \in S$ are called *simple* or *fundamental reflections* but every element of the form $wsw^{-1}$ ($s \in S, w \in W$) deserves the name *reflection* as well. Let $R$ be the system of all reflections of $(W, S)$.

**Is there a nice characterization of pairs $(W, R)$ that arise this way? By “nice” I mean that I don’t want to choose simple reflections first.**

My main aim is to better understand Weyl groups and root systems/data and their relation to parabolic subgroups of (algebraic) reductive groups, but again without necessarily choosing positive roots or a minimal parabolic subgroup. In particular, I would be content with an answer that only applies to finite groups as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is what's sometimes called the "dual approach" to reflection groups and their braid groups.  A good place to start would be

- D. Bessis, The Dual Braid Monoid, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ansens.2003.01.001 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101158

and go reference-chasing from there (including the Birman--Ko--Lee and Brady and Brady--Watt papers Bessis cites).  In particular, Bessis's Question 1.1.1 (in the arXiv version, I'm not sure if the numbering is the same in the published version) is morally equivalent to your question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1810947)

Comment: The internet is such a strange place, full of such strange people. Both arXiv and DOI are stable links; that's the whole point of DOI, it will always point to the published version of the paper.  They will be there long after some server crash wipes all traces of this post from math.SE.

Comment: For me, an ArXiv or DOI reference is perfectly fine, thank you! I’ll hopefully get around to looking at this soon (I have mostly moved on to other endeavors by now). I’ll accept if it is what I was looking for.

Comment: Ah, yes. My question is essentially their question 1.1.1 (which apparently is open?). This seems like a good starting point, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  It is also my takeaway from Bessis's paper (and what I know about the broader related literature, which is not a lot) is that a lot is known about these presentations, but not a characterization that allows one to pick them out among all group presentations.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably different angles to look at what constitutes a "reflection". My favorite is a transformation in $n$-dimensional space  that preserves an $n-1$-dimensional subspace. The "root" can be associated with the 1-dimensional subspace that isn't preserved. You can add restrictions that its order=2 which gives the normal definition. Some generalization allow other orders which gives complex reflection groups...You can probably generalize when $n-2$-dimensional subspace is preserved...though the $n-1$ case is already very rich in structure. So all reflections are defined and you can take them to be the generators of the group; the "simple" roots just give you a minimal set of generators.

Here's an example for the "order matrix" using simple reflections only and all of them. (per comments below)

```
orders_simple:=[
[1,3,2],
[3,1,3],
[2,3,1]];

orders_full:=[
[1,3,2,3,3,3],
[3,1,3,3,3,2],
[2,3,1,3,3,3],
[3,3,3,1,2,3],
[3,3,3,2,1,3],
[3,2,3,3,3,1]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not quite what I’m looking for. I’m really hoping to get a purely group theoretic condition on the pair $(W, R)$, similar to the condition on $(W, S)$ given in the question. Essentially something that is equivalent to “There exists a subset $S \subset R$ such that $(W, S)$ is a Coxeter system and $R = \{ wsw^{-1} | s \in S, w \in W \}$” but without making the $S$ part of the definition.

Comment: Like you can define a root system without specifying which roots are positive. Maybe “$(W, R)$ is the Weyl group of a root system together with the set of (reflections associated to) the roots” is the best I can hope for (even though is does not give quite all Coxeter groups); but not appealing directly to reflections in space would be appealing to me.

Comment: How about this : start with $(W,S)$, generate $R$ then calculate $ord(r_i r_j)$; that should give you another Coxeter type presentation of the same group; a less efficient one maybe but it treats all reflections the same way. For example take the reflection group $[3,3]$ of order $24$ it has 3 simple reflections and 6 total. I added the "order matrix" for the simple roots and for all roots in the answer

Comment: I don’t think that works: For example, if you start with $(S_3, \{(1~2), (2~3)\})$ and you add the third reflection, i.e. $(1~3)$, you end up with the presentation $$\langle r, s, t | r^2 = s^2 = t^2 = (rs)^3 = (rt)^3 = (st)^3 = 1 \rangle,$$ but this group is not $S_3$ (for example, you cannot recover the relation $(1~2)(2~3)(1~2) = (1~3)$).

Comment: you're right it doesn't work...strike what I said